# .htaccess redirect and rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect my user profiles.

The code does work on all "variables", even on "profiles" that dont exist for example localhost/test/flfladlfadl. The page that appears looks almost the same like the existing "profiles" but lacks functionality. The goal is to redirect non existing profiles to an error site ("flfladlfadl" dont exist in database)

My .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?pageprofile=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an htaccess thing, as it's not htaccess which is checking if the item exists in your database.

Let's say you assign the resulting row to $user, you would do something like:

```
if(!$user)
{
  // do something else, maybe a 404 not found
}
```

Comment: im trying to redirect urls, making them easier to remember. why isnt there an error for an non existing link(the non existing profile)?

Comment: Because the profile existing or not is dependent on the database. Apache itself is not querying the mysql database to determine if the user exists, your php script is. Your php script can accordingly generate a 404 page or even send back the 404 header, example: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");